# How to get client system information in angular

Tags: angular, system-information

Please, How can I get the client system information listed below in Angular?

#### System

Model
Serial No

#### OPERATING SYSTEM

OS type
Architecture
HostName

#### CPU

Manufacturer
Brand
Processors
Physical Cores
Cores
Speed
Max Speed

#### Memory Layouts

Size

#### Disk Layouts

Disk Type
Disk Serial No
Disk Size

#### Network Interface

UUID(Unique Identifier)
Ip
MAC
Speed

Answer (score 1):

Whoa - that sounds pretty invasive.

However, assuming that you have the client's consent to gather this info, you can take a look at [ngx-device-detector](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-device-detector) for gathering *some* of this info (like OS and OS version), but certainly not the extreme detail that you mention.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced situation like this where I had to read system detail and network detail.

To resolve this issue we create one click install application that install on client device and request user permission to read system details and post system information back to server and with push notification we refresh page to show client information and other details which user have access to.

Answer (score 0):

you can use angular device information library. import { AngularDeviceInformationService } from 'angular-device-information';

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).